# Why is my website costing approximately £20 per day?

Tags: azure, cost-management

I have an ASP.NET website hosted on S1 which estimates costs to be £32.64 per month.

Looking at Application Insights I see nearly 45,000 requests in a 24 hour period - which is an average of 1 request every 2 seconds.

Over a period of about 36 hours I was charged nearly £24. The configuration is literally an App Service + Application Insights, nothing else, no databases or anything.

Surely this can't be right? How can I see why this is costing so much money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Microsoft employee has confirmed there is a bug in the "Current balance" notification that pops up at the top of the page.

The value in that notification continues to go down at the same rate for up to 48 hours after you have deleted a resource (in my case a database).

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on logging to file system first. Then open the log streaming blade. You'll be able to see the requests hitting the app service.
Will help narrow down what is causing so many.
Potentially the alwaysOn feature of web app, will send 1 request a minute to keep app alive.
Do you have anything else probing the app for health.
An application gateway, front door. Traffic manager etc.
Or in app insights do you have some health probe configured. Or some perf testing.
Either way, the log streaming will show you where all these requests are originating from.